# Can't login to Apple Support Communities

Tags: macos, apple-id, applecare

It seems I am unable to login to Apple Support Communities with my Apple ID. After login, I keep being directed to the following page:

https://discussions.apple.com/backsoon/error.html

Anyone else have the same problem? What can be done about this? I have already reset my Apple ID password, and deleted my browser cache, all to no avail. Thankful for any pointers.

EDIT: I have tried both Firefox and Safari - same story. Even after clearing the cache. What's happening there?

Comment: Try a different browser. If the problem does NOT follow, there is something in the old that still needs cleared.  If the problem does follow, then the problem is not on your end.

Comment: Same issue here. This is odd! Support Communities come up fine when not logged in, but as soon as I log in the page I was on comes up invalid url